# adding defaultValue of a column using Sequelize in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-cli

I have a table called "users", which has a column called "subscription_end_date".

This is the first migration a ran to add this column using sequelize migration command i.e. npx sequelize-cli db:migrate

```
'use strict';
const tableName = 'users';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.addColumn(tableName, 'subscription_end_date', {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        after: 'updatedAt',
      });

      // Set the value of subscription_end_date to 7 days from createdAt
      await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
        UPDATE users
        SET subscription_end_date = DATE_ADD(createdAt, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
      `);
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn(tableName, 'subscription_end_date');
  },
};
```

The column was added successfully and the values were also filled as the query was also included in the migration.

Now I want to add a default value for the column "subscription_end_date" which I didn't do in the previous migration.
This is the second migration I'm trying to run:

```
'use strict';
const tableName = 'users';
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.changeColumn(tableName, 'subscription_end_date', {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)'),
        });
    },
    async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.changeColumn(tableName, 'subscription_end_date', {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: null
        });
    },
};
```

But running this migration gives this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' at line 1

Also when I tried putting the defaultValue as Sequelize.NOW, the migration was successful.
Please let me know where I'm going wrong.